# Load in an image file in photoshop and place it at a specific position

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I am looking for a function to load an image and place it at specific x,y coordinates in photoshop.

I have the following code:

```
var docRef = app.activeDocument;

function MoveLayerTo(fLayer,fX,fY) {

var Position = fLayer.bounds;
Position[0] = fX - Position[0];
Position[1] = fY - Position[1];

fLayer.translate(-Position[0],-Position[1]);
}

var doc = app.documents.add();
MoveLayerTo(doc, 12, 24)

}
```

But if I try to run it I get:

```
Error 21: undefined is not an object.
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here and how I can get my code to work?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify a layer, but you provide a complete document instead. As you can see in the [Reference](http://cssdk.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sdk/1.0/docs/WebHelp/references/csawlib/com/adobe/photoshop/Document.html), `Document` has no member called `bounds`.

Also, you are working on an empty image file (calling `documents.add` and using that newly created image), but I guess you want to work on the active document.

What you perhaps want to do is to select the topmost layer of the document provided. Anyway, if this is a plain image (such as png or jpeg), the (only) existing layer is locked (i.e. you can't translate it) and you cannot unlock the background layer, so you should:

- first duplicate the layer
- remove the original layer
- translate your layer
- reduce the image to only a background image

```
var layerOrig = docRef.layers[0];
var layerCopy = layerOrig.duplicate();
layerOrig.remove();
MoveLayerTo(layerCopy, 12, 24)
docRef.flatten();
// and maybe you want to save
```

**CAREFUL**: Do this **only** with flat images (such as .png, .jpeg) but don't do that with .psd images as you flatten the image in the end (reduce it to a single background layer). If you then save that image, all layer information is lost!